# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tilt":

Tags: ruby, bundler, tilt

How to fix it?

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "tilt":
  In Gemfile:
    sprockets (>= 2.2.1) ruby depends on
      tilt (!= 1.3.0, ~> 1.1) ruby

  tilt (2.0.0)


(Bundler::VersionConflict)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:130:in `block in resolve'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `catch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:128:in `resolve'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `resolve'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:114:in `specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs_for'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:148:in `requested_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:120:in `setup'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:219:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:333:in `running_bundler'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.29/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:217:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:96:in `preload_app'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:153:in `<module:App>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/passenger-4.0.29/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Comment: what do you have in `Gemfile` (post only related gem versions)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you have in Gemfile

```
gem 'sprockets', '>= 2.2.1'
gem 'tilt', '2.0.0'
```

is `tilt` version 2.0.0 critical important? If it possible to downgrade it you can do following.

change in Gemfile

```
gem 'tilt', '1.4.1' # the previous version http://rubygems.org/gems/tilt
```

run

```
bundle update tilt
```

After this you can remove tilt version from Gemfile